# Grails - serve HTML files as UTF-8?

Tags: tomcat, grails, utf-8, mime-types, content-type

UTF-8 is broken on .html files served through tomcat through /web-app. If I open the file directly with `file:///`, it renders fine. If I view the file during run-app, it looks fine. However, when I'm deployed as a war, UTF-8 characters appear garbled.

The content-type of the response seems correct...
`Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`, and the HTML file itself even seems to have the correct meta declarations.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

Tomcat's connector is set to "UTF-8" for default URIEncoding, so I don't think that's the issue either. GSPs are rendering fine; only the HTML file has an issue.

What could be going on here?

**EDIT:**
Using firefox, I saved a local copy of the raw HTML file and the file read directly from `file:///...` for comparison. The *only* difference between the files is that the Tomcat version has all non-ascii characters replaced with this:

```
�
```

Which either renders as an empty square or question mark depending on what editor you're using. The character itself seems to be `EF BF BD`, which replaces *all* the non-ascii characters. Somehow, in serving a file, tomcat or grails is just stomping on the unicode bytes. What could do **that**?

**EDIT EDIT:**
Even this [w3 test file](http://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html) has the same behavior as my files, indicating that my files are probably fine, and there really is something up with Tomcat/Grails.

Comment: `EF BF BD` represents any invalid encoding in UTF-8; it's exactly what you'd expect if an e.g. iso 8859-1 encoded file was forced to utf-8.

Comment: I see the same results when I run with asian characters. Chinese works in run-app and fails under tomcat. Also, all editors confirm that the source HTML file is UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: Also the utf-8 test file from the w3 gets squashed. I'm going to update my question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 1.3.7, at least, cannot serve HTML files correctly. Write your own file server controller.

Answer (score 4):

Today I currently faced this exact problem locally I was able to work fine but upon deploying with tomcat or glassfish all my files were not in the right encoding. A co-worker stumbled upon the solution.

​For the encoding to work properly when using grails with tomcat, you have to set the following tomcat options:

```
server.xml:
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

catalina.sh:
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Make sure to cntl-f5 when checking results to avoid cache

Answer (score 0):

Are there any filter mappings before the `charEncodingFilter` in your web.xml?  This is a common cause of pages getting rendered with the wrong encoding.  `charEncodingFilter` should generally be the very first filter mapping in your web.xml.  Most grails plugins that insert filter mappings have special logic to insert after this one.

Comment: Yes, there were actually. I'll test this out. Is only the order of the mappings important, and not the filters themselves?

Comment: No effect. I even made sure the generated web.xml that got included in the war had it listed first, and it does, but there was no change.

Comment: Updated my question. It looks like bytes are being destroyed altogether in the served file, which confuses the hell out of me.