# How can I convert Oracle VARCHAR2 values to UTF-8 from a list of possible encodings?

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

For legacy reasons, we have a VARCHAR2 column in our Oracle 10 database—where the character encoding is set to `AL32UTF8`—that contain some non-UTF-8 values. The values are always in one of these character sets:

- US-ASCII
- UTF-8
- CP1252
- Latin-1

I've written a Perl function to fix broken values outside the database. For a value from this database column, it loops through this list of encodings and tries to convert the value to UTF-8. If the conversion fails, it tries the next encoding. The first one to convert without error is the value we keep. Now, I would like to replicate this functionality inside the database so that anyone can use it.

However, all I can find for this is the [`CONVERT` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm), which never fails, but inserts a replacement character for characters it does not recognize. So there is no way, as far as I can tell, to know when the conversion failed.

Therefor, I have two questions:

1. Is there some existing interface that tries to convert a string into one of list of encodings, returning the first that succeeds?
2. And if not, is there some other interface that indicates failure if it's not able to convert a string to an encoding? If so, then I could write the previous function.

---

**UPDATE:**

For reference, I have written this PostgreSQL function in PL/pgSQL that does exactly what I need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION encoding_utf8(
    bytea
) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE PLPGSQL STRICT IMMUTABLE AS $$
DECLARE
    encoding TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOREACH encoding IN ARRAY ARRAY[
        'UTF8',
        'WIN1252',
        'LATIN1'
    ] LOOP
        BEGIN
            RETURN convert_from($1, encoding);
        EXCEPTION WHEN character_not_in_repertoire OR untranslatable_character THEN
            CONTINUE;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

I'd dearly love to know how to do the equivalent in Oracle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the key information about the illegal characters in UTF-8 from @collapsar, as well as some digging by a co-worker, I've come up with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reencode(string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    encoded VARCHAR2(32767);
    type  array_t IS varray(3) OF VARCHAR2(15);
    array array_t := array_t('AL32UTF8', 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'WE8ISO8859P1');
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..array.count LOOP
        encoded := CASE array(i)
            WHEN 'AL32UTF8' THEN string
            ELSE CONVERT(string, 'AL32UTF8', array(i))
        END;
        IF instr(
            rawtohex(
                utl_raw.cast_to_raw(
                    utl_i18n.raw_to_char(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(encoded), 'utf8')
                )
            ),
            'EFBFBD'
        ) = 0 THEN
            RETURN encoded;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END;
```

Curiously, it never gets to WE8ISO8859P1: WE8MSWIN1252 converts every single one of the list of 800 or so bad values I have without complaint. The same is not true for my Perl or PostgreSQL implementations, where CP1252 fails for some values but ISO-8859-1 succeeds. Still, the values from Oracle seem adequate, and appear to be valid Unicode (tested by loading them into PostgreSQL), so I can't complain. This will be good enough to sanitize my data, I think.

Comment: what happens in your code is that you *first* try to convert your input data to al32utf8 by caling 'convert', thereafter checking whether the operation succeeded. however, for byte-oriented character sets - which cp1252 happens to be, each encoding has the length of exactly 1 byte - conversion to unicode will never fail. thus your check will succeed and the function `reencode` will exit. please note that it is impossible to distiguish between byte-encoded source charsets by means of successful conversion to unicode - you need contextual information to do that. regards.

Comment: (cont'd). 1.) technically, my statement only applies to (byte-encoded) charsets whose glyphs are incorporated into unicode. i am not aware of any charset that wouldn't meet this criterion (hints appreciated). 2.) to identify the source charset, you may 2a.) in the particular case of latin-1 vs cp1252 check for bytes that are not mapped to glyphs in latin-1 (0x7f-0x9f) or 2b.) in general check for sequences instead of individual chars. example: A4 -> EURO (latin-15) / CURRENCY (cp1252). the latter won't occur after numbers in ordinary texts, so `<numbers> A4` would indicate latin-15.

Comment: Alas, I have no contextual information, and so am just cleaning up some old stuff. A few thousand converted to CP1252 out of over a billion records is something we can live with.

Answer (score 3):

to check whether your database column contains invalid utf-8 use the following query:

```
 select CASE
            INSTR (
                  RAWTOHEX (
                      utl_raw.cast_to_raw (
                          utl_i18n.raw_to_char (
                                utl_raw.cast_to_raw ( <your_column> )
                              , 'utf8'
                          )
                      )
                  )
                , 'EFBFBD'
            )
        WHEN 0 THEN 'OK'
        ELSE 'FAIL' 
        END
   from <your_table>
      ;
```

given that your db charset is al32utf8.

note that `EF BF BD` represents an [illegal encoding in utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487144/grails-serve-html-files-as-utf-8).

as all the other charsets you indicate are byte-oriented, transformation to unicode will never fail but possibly produce different code points. without contextual information automated determination of the actual source charset won't be possible.

best regards, carsten

ps:
oracle names for charsets:
`CP1252` -> `WE8MSWIN1252`
`LATIN-1` -> `WE8ISO8859P1`

Comment: Yeah, we don’t know what the original character set was, so I just want to get the values UTF-8 clean. Based on your suggestion, as well as an initial implementation by a co-worker, I've come up with a function I think is pretty close to what I need. I will post it in a separate answer.